# How Facebook and Truecaller always running its process and services in background even though it's killed by ram cleaner?

Tags: java, android

I want to develop an android app in which its service and process needs to run always in the background. Can anyone help me to implement like that?

Answer (score 0):

In android, whenever a Service is killed, the OnDestroy() method is called.
You can restart the service here, by sending out a broadcast to a BroadcastReciever class which you will have to create. In this class, you will override the OnRecieve() method and then restart the service inside this method. You will also have to register this class in you manifest file.

Broadcasts: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html

Services: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

To summarize,

1. Create a class that extends the BroadcastReciever class, and override the onRecive method.
2. In theonRecieve method, restart you service (presumably by a 
   ServiceManager)
3. Send a broadcast to this, when you service is being destroyed.